# Get term plain text aliased url from tid

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I realise that this is similar to other questions posted, but they all seem to involve using `print l()` to output a fully formed anchor.

What I need is just the uri, output in plain text to use directly in the node template. I nearly got there with the following, but end up with the unaliased version:

```
<?php
  if (isset($node->field_source_of_tid['und'][0]['tid']) && $node->field_source_of_tid['und'][0]['tid']) :
    $term=taxonomy_term_load($node->field_source_of_tid['und'][0]['tid']);
    $term_uri = taxonomy_term_uri($term);
    $output = $term_uri['path'];
endif; ?>
```

And I use the output as so:

```
<a href="<?php print render($output); ?>">A BUTTON </a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7)

> Generates an internal or external URL.

e.g.

```
$output = url($term_uri['path']);
```